# cannot resolve GlideApp on glide:4.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use glide:4.2.0 in my project. after adding

@GlideModule
    public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}

it say Error:(16, 8) error: class MainActivity clashes with package of same name
also GlideApp doesn't work

Comment: take a look at this link http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

Comment: See https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1945.

Comment: I posted answer here: [Look at this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53533267/1318946)

Answer (score 5):

Just use android studio -> menu ->build ->Make Project ,then the GlideApp will generate in the build/generated/source.....

But I have another problem , I can't use the GlideApp in the kotlin class, when I build the app, gradle will 'KotlinExt.kt: Unresolved reference: GlideApp'

Also, make sure when using Kotlin, to use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.x.x'

Answer (score 0):

I successful solve the problem by Add below line to gradle ans sync

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

Create a class and call it SkyGlideModule ( your may give it any name )

@GlideModule
public class SkyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

```
File mediaCacheDirectory;
SkyConstants skyConstants = new SkyConstants();
public static final int DiskCacheInBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
public static final String DiskCacheName = "MyAppCacheDirectory";

@Override
public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {

    builder.setDiskCache(
            new ExternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, DiskCacheName, DiskCacheInBytes));

    builder.setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(DiskCacheInBytes));
    builder.setBitmapPool(new LruBitmapPool(DiskCacheInBytes));

}

private class DiskCacheFactory extends DiskLruCacheFactory {
    DiskCacheFactory(final Context context, final String diskCacheName, long diskCacheSize) {
        super(new CacheDirectoryGetter() {
            @Override
            public File getCacheDirectory() {
                return mediaCacheDirectory;
            }

        }, (int) diskCacheSize);
    }
}
```

}

Add below line to Manifest

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.myapp.packageName.ClassWithGridleModule" android:value="GlideModule" tools:node="remove" />
```

Finally call this

```
  GlideApp.with(context)
                .load("urlToOnlineImage")
                .into("imageviefindbyid");
```