# Unable to Resolve GlideApp in Glide 4.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-glide

After Going Through tons of forums about same issue, I still not been able to resolve the `GlideApp` error. It says it cannot be resolved. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

*Here is the java class to use details from above*

[image]

My `build.gradle` file already contains:

```
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Both and also I have class with below code:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class CustomAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
}
```

And I'm using this to to request for:

*When I use `Glide.with` Then it Error says*

[image]

But still it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: juse Glide only instead of GlideApp

Comment: Then it gives me error in "with: if i used only Glide.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Quicklearner Please check I have included every details of my problem in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

[**DEMO**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/samples/flickr/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/flickr/FlickrGlideModule.java)

```
@GlideModule
public class FlickrGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

  @Override
  public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
    super.applyOptions(context, builder);
    builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888));
  }

  @Override
  public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide,
      @NonNull Registry registry) {
    registry.append(Photo.class, InputStream.class, new FlickrModelLoader.Factory());
  }

  // Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
  @Override
  public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Read  [**`AppGlideModule`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html)

**FYI**

Your **`loadImage`** method will be

```
public static void loadImage(Context ctx,RequestOptions glideRequests, String url, ImageView imageView) {
        loadImage(ctx,glideRequests, url, imageView, DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
    }

    public static void loadImage(Context ctx,RequestOptions glideRequests, String url, ImageView imageView, DiskCacheStrategy diskCacheStrategy) {

                 Glide.with(ctx)
                    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).error(R.drawable.ic_stub))
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(url).into(imageView);
    }
```

**Then**

```
ImageUtil.loadImage(context,options,obj.getPhotoUrl(),avatarImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nice information but still I'm not able to resolve the problem. Almost project is completed but only this error is I'm unable to solve here is the whole project the GlideApp module is inside util https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/Physicscircle

Comment: @Inellij Please check I have added all the details and edited my question.

Comment: so If I use GlideApp it shows error and when I use Glide.with it shows error...can you please guide me.if you need I have teamviewer opened...., I would love to share my pc with you..!!

Comment: yes I have added in question and edited it in my second image. First image creates request and in second image in imageutil class where method is implemented. please check

Comment: @BirNepali got the point. Add first param `RequestOptions requestOptions`

Comment: where should I add this...can you please help me..should I replace GlideRequests glideRequests with RequestOptions requestOptions in second image or else?

Comment: @BirNepali Kindly check my edited answer. Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help here is the error after I used what you have shared with me  https://ibb.co/ndR34p     https://ibb.co/eF5fjp

Comment: @BirNepali omg! why you remove `RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();`

Comment: huge respect for you...almost  there and yes I forget to add Request option and I added on my class later here the screenshot of before and now https://ibb.co/kp47fU  and https://ibb.co/eX1QZp. Now only error I am getting is on listener. How can I resolve it....!! you have my vote and also helpful vote .

Comment: @BirNepali  You can delete this method. Not using. `public static void loadImage(GlideRequests glideRequests, String url, ImageView imageView,
                                 RequestListener<Drawable> listener) {
        glideRequests.load(url)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .listener(listener)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                .into(imageView);
    }`

Comment: sorry for late reply..yes you deserve up vote...I will definitely do that..one last hurdle..I was able to resolve all the error except some properties I cannot resolve they are diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None) and fitCenter() and CenterCrop() and .skipMemoryCache(true)...should I remove them or is there anyway that in Bitmap we can resolve them..I searched for online but found none that can help me. here is the image https://ibb.co/d7G9C9

Comment: @BirNepali You should add `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in your xml Imageview section or `public static void loadImage(Context ctx,RequestOptions glideRequests, String url, ImageView imageView, DiskCacheStrategy diskCacheStrategy) {
          glideRequests.fitCenter();
     Glide.with(ctx)......`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Import `Glide` by adding this in gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Then use this code

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_male)
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                // log exception
                Log.e("TAG", handle error case", e);
                return false; 
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 Log.e("TAG", handle success case here", e);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(avatarImageView);
```

Comment: I have edited my question where I have another class to receive request. whenever I change any variable then next class ask me to change signature of class. I have added above my question.

Comment: did my answer help you ?

Comment: nope...it still shows error...!! can you kindly please help me from Teamviewr..I would love to share my pc with you..!! Almost project is done but only this one problem has not been resolved..would be very grateful of you.

Comment: i cannot use teamviewer right now dear, but later , anyways you can share your error here

Comment: you just want to show the image using glide right?

Comment: yes...but I have also separate class where I handle the request from different class. I have also included that class in my second image above.

Comment: i got it , you dont need to use ImageUtil.loadImage method , you can easily use Glide.with(context)
        .load(url).into(avatarImageView);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179881/discussion-between-quick-learner-and-bir-nepali).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like great discussion going on. Don't worry. I have solution.

Follow the steps:

#### Add dependency as follow (I used latest version)

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

#### Create package (as I always used structured code) myglide and copy/paste following class:

```
@GlideModule
public class SampleGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
    }
}
```

Now you can press **`CTRL+F9`** OR you can click on **`Make Project`** option in **`Build`** menu. 
It will generate one file automatically *(You can see by pressing CTRL and hover on ClassName in File.)*

```
final class GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl extends GeneratedAppGlideModule {
  private final SampleGlideModule appGlideModule;
  ....
}
```

Now you can use **GlideApp** class very easily.

Feel free to contact me if you get any error.

Hope it will helps you. I love Glide as always. <3